# X509 Certificate Custom validation (for specific paths)

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-security, ssl-certificate

Im trying to validate self-signed certificate against self-signed root CA (given by service provider who will make calls to my service). Now, if i enable two way ssl all works fine but SSL requirement is globally enforced. I need to use it just for one request, and for one user. Other services should not be affected and since there is no way (unless im mistaken) of enabling it for specific paths, i deactivated two ssl and instead, in my controller im doing this:

```
    String auth = request.getHeader("Authorization");


    X509Certificate[] cert = (X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");

    ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
    try {


        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        InputStream certInStream = resourceLoader.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("keystore/CaCertificate.jks");
        trustStore.load(certInStream, "changeit".toCharArray());

        TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("X509");
        trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

        TrustManager[] trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

        for (TrustManager tm: trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers())
            ((X509TrustManager)tm).checkClientTrusted(cert, "RSA");
    }
```

Thus my question is, is this method of validating certificate same as default?
Another thing is that unless i configure the following correctly:

```
server.ssl.trust-store=keystore/truststore.jks
server.ssl.trust-store-password=pass
server.ssl.trust-store-type= JKS
server.ssl.client-auth=want
```

then getAttribute method returns null. And i very much want to know why it happens. So the certificate still goes validation but request doesnt fail and its attrbute(SSL one) is not set if client certificate is not trusted? So essentially the code i wrote is useless and i can just check if following is null?

```
X509Certificate[] cert = (X509Certificate[])request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

please help im thoroughly lost.

EDIT:
For testing purposes im using .net 4.5 HttpWebRequest. With this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => 
                {
                    return true;
                }
```

Comment: i have few services that normal users use. and one service that should be called by a payment provider, i want to authenticate only the payment provider using ssl not other normal users. This is why i cant enforce global 2 way ssl. So i have to check ssl manually. But if i dont set up truststore ssl attribute of request is null.

Comment: How is it a client problem if some clients must use SSL others dont? i dont see how that would be possible without tweaking from backend.